# Android run launcher shortcut through shell

Tags: android, shell, android-intent, adb, shortcut

I don't know how can I convert shortcut intent to shell command

I'm trying to run this #intent on shell:

```
#Intent;
action=io.github.sds100.keymapper.ACTION_TRIGGER_KEYMAP_BY_UID;
component=io.github.sds100.keymapper/.api.LaunchKeyMapShortcutActivity;
S.io.github.sds100.keymapper.EXTRA_KEYMAP_UID=2bba7f4f-0a7e-44d6-828d-ec87c0c868cd;
end
```

App name is KeyMapper.

I've tried this code on shell (need root, if i don't use it tries to run from another user idk why):

```
am start -a io.github.sds100.keymapper.ACTION_TRIGGER_KEYMAP_BY_UID;component=io.github.sds100.keymapper/.api.LaunchKeyMapShortcutActivity;S.io.github.sds100.keymapper.EXTRA_KEYMAP_UID=2bba7f4f-0a7e-44d6-828d-ec87c0c868cd
```

But returned this:

```
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=io.github.sds100.keymapper.ACTION_TRIGGER_KEYMAP_BY_UID flg=0x10000000 }

/system/bin/sh: <stdin>[1]: S.io.github.sds100.keymapper.EXTRA_KEYMAP_UID=2bba7f4f-0a7e-44d6-828d-ec87c0c868cd: not found
```

Expected to trigger an KeyMapper action

EDIT:

Tried this:

```
am start --user 0 -a io.github.sds100.keymapper.ACTION_TRIGGER_KEYMAP_BY_UID --es S.io.github.sds100.keymapper.EXTRA_KEYMAP_UID=2bba7f4f-0a7e-44d6-828d-ec87c0c868cd --el io.github.sds100.keymapper/.api.LaunchKeyMapShortcutActivity
```

And returned this:

```
Starting: Intent { act=io.github.sds100.keymapper.ACTION_TRIGGER_KEYMAP_BY_UID cmp=io.github.sds100.keymapper/.api.LaunchKeyMapShortcutActivity (has extras) }
```

But it didn't really started the shortcut

Answer (score 0):

You cant use "ACTION_TRIGGER_KEYMAP_BY_UID" in the package string name
you need first specified the package name and the class name like this

```
am start -a io.github.sds100.keymapper/.api.LaunchKeyMapShortcutActivity
```

after this you can try to add your other data

Comment: The -a in 'am start' makes the package string be an action